# Define skewed gaussian function that returns two parameters after fitting

Tags: python-3.x, function, gaussian

I know such questions have been asked a few times already, but still I can't get it: I want to define a function that returns more than one parameter.

I have written the following code to fit data to a skewed gaussian function:

```
def skew(x, sigmag, mu, alpha, c, a):
    normpdf = (1/(sigmag*np.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*np.exp(-(np.power((x-mu),2)/(2*np.power(sigmag,2))))
    normcdf = (0.5*(1+sp.erf((alpha*((x-mu)/sigmag))/(np.sqrt(2)))))
    return 2*a*normpdf*normcdf + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(skew, xdata, ydata, p0=(5.5, 57636., 4.5, 0.0001, 0.01))
y_fit= skew(xdata, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4])
```

However, my idea is to get the peak of the data distribution, and not the mean returned by the `skew` function as one of the best fit values. Therefore, I would need the `mode` of the distribution, which can be calculated as the maximum of the `normpdf`.

How do I get `normpdf` from my defined function and get its maximum over fitted data?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your two variables, `normpdf` is the normal probability density function and `normcdf` is the normal cumulative distribution function? And you want to find some local maximum in your pdf?

Comment: @Miket25, yes: I need the peak of the distribution, also called the "mode" (the equivalent of the "mean" in the gaussian distribution). For skewed gaussian, the mode is given by the maximum of the PDF. I found alternative ways to get the mode, yet I need to understand how to work with functions in the above-described situations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `normpdf` calculates the pdf for a fixed `x` value. Unless `skew` is being called within a loop where `x` is changing, `xdata` is only one point in the domain, and there's no way to determine the maximum with one point. That is unless you do calculus on the function?

Comment: As you can see from the code, I call `skew` within `curve_fit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example we can run, and you supplied no sample output, but I think I see the question. You appear to be asking about the comma ',' tuple unpacking operator used in the `popt, pcov = curve_fit(...)` line. We will leave that line unchanged, and recover `mode` from your function. Use this:

```
def skew2(x, sigmag, mu, alpha, c, a):
    normpdf = (1 / (sigmag * np.sqrt(2 * math.pi))) * np.exp(-(np.power((x - mu), 2) / (2 * np.power(sigmag, 2))))
    normcdf = (0.5 * (1 + sp.erf((alpha * ((x - mu) / sigmag)) / (np.sqrt(2)))))
    return 2 * a * normpdf * normcdf + c, max(normpdf)

def skew(x, sigmag, mu, alpha, c, a):
    return skew2(x, sigmag, mu, alpha, c, a)[0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(skew, xdata, ydata, p0=(5.5, 57636., 4.5, 0.0001, 0.01))
y_fit, mode = skew2(xdata, *popt[:5])
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please comment a bit the code?Why do you need to define two functions?

Comment: I didn't write curve_fit(), and assume its 1st arg should return a single value. But you said you wanted a value from normpdf. So skew() returns one value, and skew2() returns two values to accommodate your stated need. They come back as a tuple, and are parsed by projection with `[0]`, or with comma unpacking in the last line, into y_fit and mode.